# Deleting repeated characters in a string bash script

Tags: string, bash, shell, bash4

I have this code to delete repeated characters in a string:

```
awk -v FS="" '{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)str=(++a[$i]==1?str $i:str)
}
END {print str}' <<< "AABBCC"
```

The result is:

> ABC

Which is exactly what I want; but the problem is when I pass a variable it removes the repeated letters but it doesn't update the value of the variable. For example:

```
KEY=AABBCC
awk -v FS="" '{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)str=(++a[$i]==1?str $i:str)
}
END {print str}' <<< "$KEY"
echo the new key is: $KEY
```

The result is:

> ABC
>
> the new key is: AABBCC

How can I get the updated version of the KEY?

Comment: You just need to assign the result of the awk command to the variable again. `KEY=$(awk ...)`

Comment: @EtanReisner sorry i didn't notice that. it was a mistake when i rewrote the code.

Comment: Which is what I responded to him in my previous comment. Clearly your original code was working.

Comment: @EtanReisner do you have an answer to this question?

Comment: My answer is in that first comment of mine. And was repeated by both submitted answers below. I didn't feel the need to submit a real answer for this and was going to let someone else do that if they wanted to get credit for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
KEY=AABBCC
KEY=$(awk -v FS="" '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)str=(++a[$i]==1?str $i:str) } END {print str}' <<< "$KEY")
echo $KEY
```

Output:

```
ABC
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign the output of the awk command to the variable like so:

```
KEY=AABBCC
KEY=$(awk -v FS="" '{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)str=(++a[$i]==1?str $i:str)
}
END {print str}' <<< "$KEY")
echo the new key is: $KEY
```

will result in 
`the new key is: ABC`